# linq: how to set condition that select all the records generated within the last 20 minutes?

Tags: linq

I can use datediffmin() method in SQL, but is there a same method in Linq? Say one field in my table is GeneratedTime which is datetime type. I want to select all records that generated within the last 20min.

```
    return(from m in dc.Msgs
           where m.GeneratedTime ????
           select m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
return (from m in dc.Msgs
        where m.GeneratedTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-20)
        select m)
```